# How to force a refresh on a Kendo UI Grid filled with remote data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI Grid filled with info from a remote source and I want to force a refresh on the information displayed after a Kendo UI Window on my website is closed.

I tried this:

```
var grid = $("#usuariosGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.refresh();
```

But it didn't work, this is how I create the Kendo UI Grid:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: root_url + "/usuario/index",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: "Response",
        total: "Count"
    },
    serverPaging: false,
    pageSize: 2
});
$("#usuariosGrid").kendoGrid({
    pageable: {
        refresh: true
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "UsuarioId", title: "ID", width: "100px" },
        { field: "Nombre", title: "Nombre", width: "100px" },
        { field: "ApellidoP", title: "Apellido Paterno", width: "100px" },
        { field: "ApellidoM", title: "Apellido Materno", width: "100px" },
        { command: [{  text: "Editar", click: editFunction }, { text: "Eliminar", click: deleteFunction }], title: " ", width: "200px" }
    ],
    dataSource: ds
});
```

I looked at the documentation but didn't come across a method to do this.

On a side note, I've been wondering how to display a loading animation on the Kendo UI Grid while the data is being loaded into it, it is shown after it's been loaded and I'm clicking through the pages of the grid, but when there's no data, it looks collapsed and I would like to display a loading animation to make it look filled while the info is being loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @NicholasButtler suggests, use `ds.read()` for forcing a read. Depending on your `DataSource` definition, the result might be cached. Check [this](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read.cache) on enabling/disabling `transport.read.cache`.

For replacing the loading image redefine the class `.k-loading-image`. Example:

```
.k-loading-image {
    background-image:url('http://24.media.tumblr.com/cfa55f70bbc5ce545eed804fa61a9d26/tumblr_mfpmmdCdWA1s1r5leo1_500.gif')
}
```

**EDIT** In order to guarantee that you have space enough for displaying the image add the following style definition:

```
#grid .k-grid-content {
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Fiddle example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/nYYHk/1/

Comment: ok the reading works, but with the loading image, what I want to do is to show an animation while the data is being retrieved from the server. When the data is being loaded for the first time, the grid looks collapsed and I want it to look "filled" with the animation, because normally it looks like it's not doing anything, so I want the loading animation to be present to give the impression of background work being performed.

Comment: What about setting a min-height for the grid? This should leave space for letting the gif get shown!

Comment: I added a min-height, but it only affected the bottom part of the grid, no where the data should be displayed, but instead the area where the page numbers are.

Comment: See my last **EDIT** or here a running example http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/nYYHk/1/

Comment: thanks, isn't out there a reference documentation for all of the styles selectors in kendo UI?

Comment: Not all but at least some in [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/appearance-styling). Then you will have to take a look into the generated HTML and be imaginative :-)

Comment: by the way, if no results are returned, how do I put a message of not items found in the grid?

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with the loading image not showing when loading remote data, but I noticed it was only on certain grids.

Turns out, if you configure the grid with: `scrollable: false` option, the loading image shows as expected. There's no need to have a `min-height` in the CSS and there's no need to have a scrollable grid if you're also paging.